# How to capture the year in a flow

Tags: flow, date

I'm trying to create a flow and it needs to create a record that has the next year. I need to be able to check what Year we are in, so I can add one to it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a formula field, you could just use YEAR(TODAY)+1